# Cannot wrap StripPrefix in another function (missing ServeHTTP method)

Tags: go, interface

I want to wrap func StripPrefix inside another function and do some client session checking before making a file server. All the sessions are stored in a MySQL database table for implementing multiple web server for one website.

```
func RegisterHandlers() {
    http.Handle("/", fileHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/login", loginHandler)
}

func fileHandler() http.Handler {
    //Check session in the database
    return http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("client/index")))
}
```

**Error Message**

The error message said that missing `ServeHTTP` method. I don't understand why since I just wrap it in another function and return exactly `http.StripPrefix`.

```
./index.go:9: cannot use fileHandler (type func() http.Handler) as type http.Handler in argument to http.Handle:
    func() http.Handler does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http.Handle` expects a function that takes an `http.ResponseWriter` and an `*http.Request`. Your file handler function does not take either of these arguments. Instead, you want to pass in the handler returned from a *call* to your fileHandler function. However, if you do this as-is, you will only be checking the credentials once instead of on every HTTP call, which is probably not what you wanted. Instead, you have to return a handler function that wraps both your session check, and a call to the file servers `Handle` method. You could even have it wrap a generic handler (similar to how `StripPrefix` works) so that you can reuse it to check the session for multiple different types of requests. Something like the following:

```
func RegisterHandlers() {
    http.Handle("/", checkSession(http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("client/index")))))
    http.HandleFunc("/login", loginHandler)
}

func checkSession(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return HandlerFunc(func(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
        //Check session in the database
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```